# Is this $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof of $\lim_{x\to p} \ln(x) = \ln(p)$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to p} \ln(x) = \ln(p)$

Let $\epsilon>0$.

$|\ln(x)-\ln(p)| = \Big|\ln\Big(\frac{x}{p}\Big)\Big| $

Observe that:

$$\Big|\ln\Big(\frac{x}{p}\Big)\Big| < \epsilon \iff
-\epsilon < \ln\Big(\frac{x}{p}\Big) < \epsilon \iff
e^{-\epsilon} < \frac{x}{p} < e^\epsilon \iff
pe^{-\epsilon} < x < pe^\epsilon \iff
pe^{-\epsilon} - p < x - p < pe^\epsilon - p \iff
p(e^{-\epsilon} - 1) < x - p < p(e^\epsilon-1)$$
$$ \iff -p(e^\epsilon - 1) < x - p < p(e^\epsilon - 1) \iff
|x - p| < p(e^\epsilon - 1)
$$

Note that $e^\epsilon - 1 \geq -e^{-\epsilon}+1$, since $e^x-1$ is convex, $-e^{-x}+1$ is concave and they share $y=x$ as tangent in $x=0$. Then $-(e^\epsilon - 1) \leq e^{-\epsilon}-1 $.

Then make $\delta = p(e^\epsilon - 1) > 0$.

So we have:
$|x - p| < \delta \Rightarrow |\ln(x)-\ln(p)| < \epsilon$

I think my proof is ok, but I became confused after seeing what André Nicholas choosed for $\delta$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/314532/567288). Isn't this implying my choice for $\delta$ doesn't work?

Comment: why not? isn't this true: $e^{-\epsilon}-1 \geq -(e^{\epsilon}-1)$?

Comment: sorry, I still don't see the problem. I agree that $e^{-\epsilon} -1 < 0$, but $-(e^{\epsilon} - 1)$ is also negative...

Comment: Sorry I must have brainfarted.
Let me rephrase the problem.
The '$\iff$' in this statement

$$p(e^{-\epsilon} - 1) < x - p < p(e^\epsilon-1) \iff -p(e^\epsilon - 1) < x - p < p(e^\epsilon - 1)$$

is not true and should be an $\implies$, but you need the other direction.
Indeed, we have

$$-p(e^\epsilon - 1) \leqslant p(e^{-\epsilon} - 1) < p(e^\epsilon-1)$$

so that $p(e^{-\epsilon} - 1) <  x-p \implies -p(e^\epsilon - 1) <  x-p$, but not the other way round.

Comment: and is this true?
$p(e^{-\epsilon} - 1) < x-p < p(e^{\epsilon} - 1) \iff |x-p| < p(1-e^{-\epsilon})$?

Comment: No. Think about what the LHS means and about what the RHS means, and see if they are the same. Also, notice that you do **not** need a sequence of iffs to show an $\epsilon-\delta$ limit. You need a sequence of implications from $|x-p|<\delta$ to $|f(x)-f(p)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: But the $\Leftarrow$ is true, right? since $-p(1-e^{-\epsilon}) = p(e^{-\epsilon}-1) $ . So choosing $\delta = p(1-e^{-\epsilon})$ works, correct?

Comment: You would have

$$|x-p|<p(1-e^{-\epsilon}) \iff -p(1-e^{-\epsilon}) =  p(e^{-\epsilon} - 1) < x-p < p(1-e^{-\epsilon}) < p(e^\epsilon -1) \implies  p(e^{-\epsilon} - 1) <x-p <  p(e^{\epsilon} - 1),$$

so yes. The only caveat is that perhaps it would be a good idea to include in your text the proof that $1-e^{-\epsilon} < e^\epsilon -1$ for $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: thanks a lot, now I got it. and the proof of that I already made in my original (failed) attempt to prove the limit.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that,
$$\exp\left|\ln(x) - \ln(p )\right| = 
\max\{\tfrac{x}{p},\tfrac{p}{x}\}$$

The only real issue we get with $\ln$ is at values near $0$, so to make sure we're away from it, we require $\delta < p/2$, then $|x-p|<\delta$ implies $p/2 < x$. 
By the triangle inequality
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{p} &\leq \left|\frac{p}{p}\right| + \left|\frac{x-p}{p}\right|
< 1 + \frac{\delta}{p} < e^{\delta/p}\\
\frac{p}{x} &\leq \left|\frac{x}{x}\right| + \left|\frac{p-x}{x}\right|
< 1 + \frac{\delta}{(p/2)} < e^{2\delta/p}
\end{align}

Hence $$\exp\left|\ln(x) - \ln(p )\right| < \exp(2\delta/p)$$so if $\delta = \min\{p/2, \epsilon p /2\}$, then $|\ln(x)-\ln(p )| < \epsilon$.

Comment: But isn't $|x/p| < e^{\epsilon}$ valid only when $x>p$?

Comment: No, the triangle inequality holds in either case.

If $|x-p| < \delta = p\epsilon$, then
$$\left|\frac{x}{p}\right| < 1+\delta/p = 1 + \epsilon < 1+ \epsilon + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\epsilon^n}{n!} = e^{\epsilon}$$

Comment: That part I understood, I mean this, at the begining: "$|\ln(x/p)| < \epsilon$ or equivalently $|x/p| < e^\epsilon $"

Comment: Fixed it. Hopefully it is clearer now