# A continuous function on an open interval bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

I have being taught that a continuous function on a bounded interval is bounded then I am thinking of a counterexample when the interval is open. The example I came up with was $f(x)=log(x)$ for $x \in (0,1)$, but I am kind of thinking how could I prove its continuity on $(0,1)$ from definition?

Comment: Another example is $f(x)=\frac1x$. You have been taught something wrong, or you do not remember it correctly. A continuous function on a *closed* bounded interval is bounded.

Comment: To address the second concern, the usual definition of $\log$ is as the inverse function of $\exp$ and the inverse of a monotonic function on an interval is continuous.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314518/i-need-to-prove-the-continuity-of-fx-log-x-using-a-epsilon-delta-proof) of demonstration that $log(x)$ is continuous (on $(0, +\infty)$) using the definition.

Comment: You've better have been taught that the image of a compact set unter a continuous function is compact as well.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Ah our course hasn't properly defined what compactness really means, so I am guessing that is no use for now :( (what is compactness anyways?)

Comment: In our case case it means closed and bounded.  Now $(0,1)$ is bounded, but not closed.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continous in a interval [a,b], and $I\subset[a,b]$ is an interval,
then $f|_I$ is continous.

Comment: True, and yesterday it was a rainy night in Georgia.